# auto resize and align javascript for illustrator CS5

Tags: javascript, adobe, flash-cs5

I am using illustrator CS5.
and I am using this javascript.

and I want to do, after this script, I want to align those two selections automatically top left of one of those.
How can I do?

```
var dia = new Window("dialog", "Resize", [0,0,300,170]);
dia.pane1 = dia.add("panel", [10,15,290,90], "Fit to...");
dia.radi1 = dia.pane1.add("radiobutton", [10,15,200,25], "Width");
dia.radi2 = dia.pane1.add("radiobutton", [10,40,200,50], "Height");
dia.bot1 = dia.add("button", [10,100,290,160], "do it", { name:"ok"});
dia.radi1.value = true;
dia.center();
dia.show();

sel = activeDocument.selection;
var Tmax = 0;
var Ymax = 0;
for (i = 0; i < sel.length; i++) {
    if (Tmax < sel[i].height) {
        Tmax = sel[i].height
    }
    if (Ymax < sel[i].width) {
        Ymax = sel[i].width
    }
}

for (i=0; i < sel.length; i++) {
    if (dia.radi2.value) {
        bairitu = Tmax / sel[i].height * 100;
    } else {
        bairitu = Ymax / sel[i].width * 100;
    }

    sel[i].resize(bairitu, bairitu, true, true, true, true, bairitu, Transformation.TOPLEFT);
}
```

Comment: Sounds neat, thanks for sharing. Do you have question?

Comment: yes, I want to do, after this script, I want to align those two selections automatically top left of one of those. How can I do?